# Objects re-initalization in c#

Tags: c#, object, object-initializers

Is it considered 'good practice' to re-use objects in c#.
For example: 
      Say you have a class called Anima and create an oject of type animal called monkey:

```
Animal monkey = new Animal(paramA);
monkey = new Animal(paramB);
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happens?

Comment: probably won't compile.. as 'object' is not valid identifier.. coz it's a keyword ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that sound about right. The previous instance you now lose reference to should be caught up in the next Garbage Collection cycle.